Counting total unordered pizzas in a CMIMC question

At a certain pizzeria, there are five different toppings available and
a pizza can be ordered with any (possibly empty) subset of them on it.
In how many ways can one order an unordered pair of pizzas such that
at most one topping appears on both pizzas and at least one topping
appears on neither? (CMIMC 2017/Combinatorics/7)

I am interested in how many unordered pairs of pizzas can be ordered (NO restrictions on toppings).
For each topping, you have a choice of ordering, or not ordering, giving, for each pizza:
$$2^5 \text { choices } $$
Since there are two pizzas, the number of ordered pairs of pizzas that you can order is:
$$2^5\times 2^5=2^{10}=1024$$
To convert from ordered to unordered, note that the number of identical pizzas is the number of choices for one pizza:
$$2^5=32$$
Hence, the number of unordered pairs is:
$$\frac{1024+32}{2}=528$$
Is this Count correct?
On further analysis, the question I asked seems to be this question with 5 toppings and one size of pizza.

Your Calculations are right.
We might want to confirm that, which is necessarily by using some other way to get that count.
Hence here is the Alternative Solution.
Consider topping1 , which we can

either use on both or none (Pizzas are still indistinguishable/unordered , 2 ways)
or use on one (let it be the Pizza1 , which makes them distinguishable/ordered)

When we have distinguishable/ordered Pizzas , then remaining 4 toppings can be used in 4 ways each : only Pizza1 , only Pizza2 , both Pizzas , neither Pizzas : hence it is $4^4=256$
When we have indistinguishable/unordered Pizzas , then the next topping topping2 can either make them distinguishable/ordered or leave them indistinguishable/unordered.
When we have distinguishable/ordered Pizzas , then remaining 3 toppings can be used in 4 ways each : only Pizza1 , only Pizza2 , both Pizzas , neither Pizzas , hence it is $4^3=64$
Continuing like that , the last topping topping5 can be used in 3 ways.
Let us roll back the Calculations to get :
$\{ [ (3\times2+4^1) \times 2 + 4^2 ] \times 2 + 4^3 \} \times 2 + 4^4 $
$\{ [ (6+4) \times 2 + 16 ] \times 2 + 64 \} \times 2 + 256 $
$\{ [ 20 + 16 ] \times 2 + 64 \} \times 2 + 256 $
$\{ 36 \times 2 + 64 \} \times 2 + 256 $
$\{ 72 + 64 \} \times 2 + 256 $
$\{ 136 \} \times 2 + 256 $
$ 272 + 256 $
$ 528 $
This longish way gives the "Same Count" , which is independent way to confirm that your way is right.
ADDENDUM :
Here is the visualization :

Topmost level is the over-all Count.
Every level is a topping , where $00$ indicates not using the topping , $11$ indicates Both Pizzas using the topping , $10$ indicates Pizza1 using the topping.
